# I use jekyll and need a glossary tooltip that dynamically finds the terms

Tags: tooltip, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions, glossary

Working on a site and I found this [glossary tooltip](https://github.com/erikw/jekyll-glossary_tooltip) that I can use, however it seems that I need to add the liquid tag to each instance of the terms in the glossary.

Is there any way that I can get it to detect these terms automatically?

It tells you to add this liquid tag to the terms you want the tooltip to appear on: `{% glossary term_name %}`

I understand that I can inject these but want to avoid adding this extra step when new pages are added if possible.